# How to access office local server files through an java swing app?

Tags: java, database, swing, server

***How to access office local server files through an java swing app?***

I have an Java application made using Swing. Using this app I am taking data from user and storing it in a file.

Now, currently the data stored is being stored in user's system only. Now I have a local office server, I want to dynamically add data to that file whenever users inputs some data through that app, so that whenever i want to access that file, i can see all the users data that have been input through that app.

I have searched on net, but everywhere either FTP sever or cloud is being discussed and both are not allowed. How to tackle this problem ?

Comment: Create a server app, that takes data from client (via HTTP or RMI) and stores them. In other words, you need to create your own FTP/cloud server.

Comment: Another possibility - store the data into a database, that you access via URL.

Comment: Your question is also tagged with `database` but I could not see how it is related to your question. Do you want to store your app's data in a database?

Comment: Much too broad a question for Stack Overflow. Consult a discussion site such as http://www.JavaRanch.com/. Tip: if you want to merge the data together into a single database, look into JDBC, SQL, and the H2 database.

Comment: @Abra...Is there anyway we can do this using database without any dependency , thats also my concern ?

Comment: The usual way to access a database from java is to use JDBC. In order to use JDBC you need a JDBC driver. Do you consider a JDBC driver to be a _dependency_ ?

Comment: @Abra...but what is the optimal place to keep the database ? That's where I am stuck ..i want to keep it on file server and want to made it accessible to every user but how because FTP and cloud are not allowed ...

Comment: Are all your users on the same network as the file server?

Comment: @Abra...Yes its same